# Add web project in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I have web application design only with HTML5, CSS3 and Jquery along with this i have one project with AJAX enabled WCF services to provide endpoints to the HTML pages. I also have couple of projects that have webservices used in my web application.

Now I want to use convert this application into native apps with Phonegap.
please help me on this, forward resources that we can use to convert web application into native android via phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used only used HTML, JS and CSS in your apps and no server side technologies like ASP.NET or PHP, you can easily get the entire code base running on phone gap. If you need to get the real mobile experience try mobile frameworks like jQuery Mobile or Kendo UI Mobile for UI.